# How IO operations working on F#

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, monads

There were IO monad on haskell to keep it pure. I know f#/ocaml supports mutable state but how IO operations works actually. What is corresponding concept to haskell's IO monad.

Comment: The short answer is: F# doesn't have one.

Comment: F# does not have the purity of Haskell, and explicitly allows for methods to have side effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# is not pure. It inherits the Caml tradition of allowing IO and state changes (e.g. assignment to mutable variables) everywhere. For instance:

```ml
let f : int -> int =
   fun x -> 
      printf "Hello\n";
      x+1

printf "%d\n" (f 1 + f 2)      (* prints Hello twice, then 5 *)
```

Monads can still be found in F#, though, if you want to use them.
[Computation expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) correspond to monads, roughly.

Comment: i see, what happens to return value of printf? Does it returns a value? I can't remember very well but ocaml force you to assign every return value to a variable right?

Comment: @UmurGedik There is a warning for throwing away values, but not if the return value has type `unit`, like `printf "Hello\n"` does.